# Why do I need the 'match' part of a SQL merge, in this scenario?

Tags: sql, merge, sql-server-2012

Consider the following:

```
merge into T t1
using (select ID,Col1 from T where ID = 123) t2
on 1 = 0
when not matched then insert (Col1) values (t2.Col1);
```

Cominig from a programming background, to me this translates to:

"Evaluate `false` (i.e. 1 = 0), and when it is `false` (i.e. all the time), insert."

Is it not possible to just omit the match condition?
Is it because of my select's `where` condition that I'm confused here? Should this condition be moved to the `on`?

*NOTE:*

*Due to restrictions with `output`, I cannot use `insert`. I need to output the results of this merge into a temporary table for reasons outside of the scope of what I'm asking.*

Comment: That's a very odd use of `merge`. It's not at all clear why they've not just written `insert into T(Col1) select Col1 from T where ID = 123` which should have exactly the same effect.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - haha ironically, it was you who wrote it (minus the `where`)! But I left out probably the most important bit of context as to why `merge` was used instead of `insert`, which is because of the need for `OUTPUT` to a temp table: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16331659/1017882 I added the `where` as I wanted to use a parameter to determine which records to merge. This isn't my actual code, it's for example's sake (edit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [answer you've linked to in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328806/can-i-keep-old-keys-linked-to-new-keys-when-making-a-copy-in-sql/16331659#16331659), as I've hopefully made clear, we are *abusing* the `MERGE` statement.

The query you've shown here could trivially be replaced by:

```
insert into T(Col1) select Col1 from T where ID = 123
```

However, if you want to be able to add an [`OUTPUT` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx), and that `OUTPUT` clause needs to reference both the newly inserted data *and* data from the source table, you're not allowed to write such a clause on an `INSERT` statement.

So, we instead use a `MERGE` statement, but not for its intended purpose. The entire purpose is to force it to perform an `INSERT` and write our `OUTPUT` clause.

If we examine the documentation for [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), we see that the only clause in which we can specify to perform an `INSERT` is in the `WHEN NOT MATCHED [BY TARGET]` clause - in both the `WHEN MATCHED` and `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` clauses, our only options are to `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.

So, we have to write the `MERGE` such that matching always fails - and the simplest way to do that is to say that matching should occur when `1 = 0`<sup>1</sup> - which, hopefully, is never.

---

<sup>1</sup>Since SQL Server doesn't support [boolean literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170688/sql-server-boolean-literal/7171264#7171264)

Comment: Thanks very much! I understand now, I was completely misunderstanding the purpose of the match. Thanks again.