# Output Inserted.Id AND another field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @OutProduct TABLE 
(
    ProductID INT,
    BulkProductId INT
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Products 
        ( EanCode , 
          ChangedDateTime , 
          ChangedById , 
          Deleted  
        ) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, BulkProducts.Id INTO @OutProduct (ProductID, BulkProductId)
SELECT  EanCode , 
        GETDATE(), 
        GETDATE(),
        0 
FROM dbo.BulkProducts 
WHERE ProductId is NULL
```

Assuming `Products.Id` & `BulkProducts.Id` are auto-incrementing identity columns:

What I'm trying to achieve:

`@OutProduct` temp table contains tuples made up of the just-inserted `Products.Id` and the Id of the row in `BulkProducts`.

What I've stumbled upon: `BulkProducts.Id` cannot be used in the `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, BulkProducts.Id INTO` statement, as it's not valid syntax.

How can I solve this?

EDIT: I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: You can [abuse `MERGE`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328806/can-i-keep-old-keys-linked-to-new-keys-when-making-a-copy-in-sql) which lets you do an insert but also reference the source table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to explore `MERGE`:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.Products
USING dbo.BulkProducts AS src
    ON 1 = 0 -- Never match
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(EanCode, ChangedDateTime, ChangedById, Deleted)
    VALUES(src.EanCode, GETDATE(), GETDATE(), 0)
OUTPUT
    inserted.Id,
    src.Id
INTO @OutProduct;
```

Reference:

[Dr. OUTPUT or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the MERGE by Adam Machanic](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/08/24/dr-output-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-merge.aspx)

Comment: On the 2nd to last line: `A MERGE statement must be terminated with a semicolon (;)` EDIT: Yeah, you forgot a colon on the 2nd to 2nd-to-last line.

Comment: This is great. However, I don't seem to be able to adapt your example to my case, aka `INSERT` with `SELECT FROM` statement, mind helping me with this?

Comment: Have you tried running it and checking the result? `MERGE` is used as a workaround for your problem.

Comment: Ohh! I am dumb. I didn't realise that the `VALUES(..` actually use columns from `src`, which is `BulkProducts` so it's kind of a `SELECT` in that case. Thanks, checking it now.

Comment: Link that needs no login http://dataeducation.com/dr-output-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-merge/