# Error while copy data using SQL Server OUTPUT ...INTO .... clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to insert data to persons table. Parallely I have to copy the inserted person id (identity column value) along with providerid from someother table to providerperson. I tried the below query but I got an error.

The multi-part identifier "P.Provider_ID" could not be bound.

```
INSERT INTO PERSONS (
            FirstName
            ,LastName
            ,Gender
            ,DOB
            ,EmailID
            ,OfficePhone
            ,Fax
            ,Mobile
            ,CertificationType_ID
            --,License
            --,StateCertificaionNo
            --,StateCertificationExpiration
            --,Comments
            ,ERTCleared
            ,IsAMR
            ,IsActive
            ,CreatedDate
            ,ModifiedDate
            ,IsCrewMember
            ,UserName
            )
        OUTPUT INSERTED.Person_ID
            ,P.Provider_ID
        --,getdate()
        --,getdate()
        --,@appuserId
        --,@appuserId
        INTO @ProviderPersons(PersonID, ProviderID)
        --00, CreatedDate, ModifiedDate, CreatedUser_ID, ModifiedUser_ID)
        SELECT S.FirstName
            ,S.LastName
            ,S.Gender
            ,S.DOB
            ,S.EmailID
            ,S.OfficePhone
            ,S.Fax
            ,S.Mobile
            ,1 AS CertificationType_ID
            ,0 AS ERTCleared
            ,CASE 
                WHEN S.IsAMR = 'Yes'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END AS IsAMR
            ,1 AS IsActive
            ,getdate() AS CreatedDate
            ,getdate() AS ModifiedDate
            ,1 AS IsCrewMember
            ,S.UserName
        FROM [dbo].[STA_CrewMembers] S
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Providers] P ON P.BusinessUnitNumber = S.BusinessUnitNumber
            OR P.NAME = S.PROVIDER
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM Persons
                WHERE EmailID = S.EmailID
                )
```

Please suggest me how to handle this in a better way. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible dupe: [Output Inserted.Id AND another field](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37339422/15498)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
OUTPUT INSERTED.Person_ID
        ,INSERTED.Provider_ID
```

you can't use table alias..Example below won't work due to table alias

```
declare @id table
(
id int
)

insert into t1
output n.id into @id
select top 10* from numbers n


select * from @id
```

Comment: I know this way by the problem is I don't insert provider_id to my persons table.

Comment: @StackUser:What is the ask then?